# Laravel condition on a DB::raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, latitude-longitude

am working on project and i need to order my adverts by distance (by using Latitude and longitude )in adition to this i want to make user abl to limite the number of adverts by ginving the max distance 
for exemple : if user want to get just the adverts in the 100 mils next to him so i order the advert and return him just the adverts that they are 100 mills away from him or less
i have done somme work ordring adverts is allready done but i don't have any idea how to continue

```
public function get_searched(Request $request){
    $annonce=DB::table("annonces")
            ->where('nomAnnonce','like','%'.$request->input("nomAnnonce").'%')
            ->orderBy(
    DB::raw('3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$request->input("lat").') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-'.$request->input("lon").') ) + sin( radians('.$request->input("lat").') ) * sin(radians(latitude)) )')
    ,'desc')  
           ->get();

    echo $annonce;
}
```

if any body can help me to finde out the why to limite the max distance and thnx

Comment: Do NOT use request input directly in a raw expression without type casting it.  This completely voids injection protection.

Comment: What is "100 mils" or "100 mills"?  Perhaps "100 miles"?  How many rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$annonce = DB::table("annonces")
    ->select('annonces.*')
    ->selectRaw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin(radians(latitude))) distance',
        [$request->input('lat'), $request->input('lon'), $request->input('lat')])
    ->where('nomAnnonce', 'like', '%'.$request->input("nomAnnonce").'%')
    ->orderBy('distance', 'desc')
    ->having('distance', '<=', $request->input('max'))
    ->get();
```

As Devon points out, using unfiltered user input is extremely dangerous ([SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Comment: hi sir , it really work but it return onlly the distance but i need to get all the values if you can help more please . this the result i get whene i put my values [{"distance":189.36192877229}].

Comment: My mistake, I fixed the answer.